# Pointer to Pointer in c, getting unexpected value

Tags: c, pointers, memory-address

I was doing some operations on pointers and came across this one:

```
int main(void)
{
    int a = 100;
    int *p, *q;
    p = &a;
    q = &p; 

    printf("\n *q= %p",*q);
    printf("\n &p= %p",&p);
    printf("\n *p= %d",*p);
    printf("\n q= %p",q);
    printf("\n p= %p",p);
    printf("\n &a= %p",&a);
    return 0;
}
```

This gives me the following output

```
 *q= 0xe5b83d74
 &p= 0x7ffee5b83d78
 *p= 100
 q= 0x7ffee5b83d78
 p= 0x7ffee5b83d74
 &a= 0x7ffee5b83d74
```

The value given by `*q` is similar to the address of `a` but is not the same. Is `*q` not referring to `&a`? **I am not trying to correct this code.** What is actually happening here?

Answer (score 3):

The pointer to `a` is being truncated and printed. You're taking a pointer to a pointer to an `int` and making it a pointer to an  `int`. It's only showing 32 bits of the pointer, which are the 32 bits that can fit into an `int`.

If you ran this on a 32-bit platform (x86, ARM) `&a` would be the same as `*q`.

You note in your title that this is a pointer to a pointer. However, it's not. It's a pointer to a pointer that's been converted to a pointer to an `int` and dereferenced. There's a difference as shown here.

Comment: @SirJoBlack You're fine. Everyone makes mistakes :).